# Gradient computation optimization inside tf.layers.dense?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a `WGAN-GP`. The following two expressions function differently as the last layer of generator:

1. `tf.layers.dense(x,dim,tf.nn.sigmoid)`
2. `tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.layers.dense(x,dim,None))`

The first one leads to stable training process and finally convergence, while the second one leads to fluctuate loss and then explode to Nan. However, I cannot see any difference between these two expressions. So I am wondering why does that happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a pure test, both expressions return the same result. It must be something else in your code or network or setup that causes the difference. Here is the test code to verify.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones([1, 10])
op1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 10, tf.nn.sigmoid, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.ones)
op2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.layers.dense(x, 10, None, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.ones))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
r1 = sess.run(op1)
r2 = sess.run(op2)
assert np.array_equal(r1, r2)
```

If the assert fails, there might be something wrong with your installation or hardware.